# include file content php

Tags: php, file, include

I want to include the content from a php file into another php file. (It's in a wordpress site)
Include or require won't work because it's just including the file, I need the content itself.
file_get_contents is also not working because it just displays my php code and does not execute it.

what function do I have to use?

Comment: `include` and `require` both execute the code. What do you need exactly? Do you need to store what the script echoes in a variable?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the content"?

Comment: Taking a wild stab in the dark....does the include file have php tags ('<?php....') in it? If not you'd need to eval() it - but I'd **strongly** recommend you don't do that until you've learnt a lot more about php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Include or require won't work because it's just including the file

Pause. What? [Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) includes the code in the file for you. I'm sure this is what you want. For instance, see the code below. `test.php` has `vars.php` included in it and its able to echo the variables from `vars.php`

```
//vars.php
----------
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
----------

//test.php
----------
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't fully understand your question either, but I think this might work for you:

```
ob_start();
include('yourfile.php');
$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

`$contents` will now contain the 'contents' (the output) of your PHP script.