# How to display the contents of a PHP file using PHP itself?

Tags: php, html

I want to create a `PHP` page which shows the contents of itself. Below is the source of the `PHP` i used. I took it from a `w3schools.com` webpage to display the contents of a text file from a PHP file.

```
<?php
   $myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
   echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
   fclose($myfile);
?>
```

It messed the webpage.

Then, I found a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647291/include-file-content-php) which is meant to include the php file into the main file.
But my attempt failed and it created a mile long webpage resulting in a recursive php (like those of recursive functions in C++).

I want a php code which displays the content of itself.

Comment: try file_get_contents() or curl

Comment: `<?php echo file_get_contents(__FILE__);` although I'm not sure what the usage of this thing might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(It's also with color :D)

```
highlight_file(__FILE__);
```

possible output:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Testing</title>         
    </head> 


    <body> 

    <?php 
        ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
        error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ?> 

    <?php  highlight_file(__FILE__);  ?>            

    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
<?php 
highlight_file(__FILE__);
?>
```

`show_source()` does the same - it's an alias. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php for details.

Comment: 'Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!', this does not "show" the code, but it is visible in the source.

Comment: That returned foophp not found when I entered foo.php for __FILE__. Then I enclosed it within quotes. Now it shows a messed up page.

Comment: It will display the content of the file but not completely on the page. it may be in the source page not on front.

Comment: @Koen Hoeijmakers : Can we run php scripts without a server that is using some sort of virtual servers?

Comment: @all sorry, fixed. Do you want it without highlighting?

Comment: @Afrish Khan You cant run php files without a server or local server like xampp or wamp, this is because php is serverside and your browser cant read php, thats why file://* does not run your php script.